# will arguments be passed to inner function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

sorry for asking such a newbie question, here is the code I saw on codeschool:

```
var hidden = mystery();
var result = hidden(3);

function mystery ( ){
    var secret = 6;
    function mystery2 ( multiplier ) { 
      multiplier *= 3;
      return secret * multiplier;
    }
    return mystery2;
}
```

My question is `hidden(3)` equal to call `mystery(3)`? if it is, after calling `mystery(3)`, why the `multiplier` which is a parameter of function `mystery2` get the value of 3? the result of this code is 54.

Comment: You mean `multiplier *= 3;`? Because someone decided that the function should do that. I don't think I understand your question. Or do you mean `var result = hidden(3);`? That's because `hidden` *is* `mystery2`, which accepts a single argument, `multiplier`. And you are passing `3` to it.

Comment: It doesn't assign 3 to `multiplier`.

Comment: @FelixKling I think hidden is mystery() not mystery2(), and thats what I am asking

Comment: No it's not. You are **calling** `mystery`, and you assign the **return value** to `hidden`. Have a look what `mystery` returns (hint: `return mystery2;`).

Comment: exactly. my question is this: calling `hidden(3)` equals to call mystery(3)? if it is, then where did `mystery2(multiplier)` get the value of multiplier to `return secret * multiplier`

Comment: the result of this code is 54. means multiplier is equal to 3. I am confused about why calling `hidden(3)` makes multiplier = 3

Comment: Again, `hidden === mystery2`. So calling `hidden(3)` is the same as `mystery2(3)`. Since `mystery2` has a parameter `multiplier`, passing an argument to `mystery2` assigns that value to the parameter. If I have a function `function foo(bar) { ... }` and call it with `foo(3)` then `bar` is set to `3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is `hidden(3)` equal to call `mystery(3)`?

No it is not. The value of `hidden` is the **return value** of `mystery()`, which is `mystery2`:

```
// you are calling mystery and assign its return value to hidden
var hidden = mystery();
```

If you want to see what value `hidden` has, just to `console.log(hidden);`.

So calling `hidden(3)` is the same as calling `mystery2(3)`. Since `mystery2` has a parameter called `multiplier`, passing `3` to `mystery2` assigns that value to the parameter.

---

I guess the important concept to understand here is the following:

In JavaScript, functions are just **objects** and therefore can be passed to or returned from a function like another object/value.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused on the *= operator that is not assignment  it is the functional equivalent of:

```
multiplier = multiplier * 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

See the shorthand operators

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

Assignment operators  and Shorthand operator    Meaning